# Can you give me insight into the time and space complexity of those pairing functions?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-compression

I am looking for a pairing function with linear time complexity.

I found

1. one [in Steven Pigeon's thesis](http://stevenpigeon.com/Publications/publications/phd.pdf) (p 115, §5.3.6.3) described in English [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20755) that works by bit interleaving.
2. another from [Regan's 1992 paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/002200009290027G?token=9BF1856B8A03DC514CFF6CA17107A3C23B6848823244B117AEAE27B4AEE1D74DF1A0662ECD63CE4B04188334EE8C2E1E) (p 289, last paragraph) that works by bit concatenation based on a state machine.

The one from Pigeon seems $O(1)$ in space and $O(n)$ in time to me, assuming fixed-length datatypes (int64). Space $O(1)$ would derive from the fact that

$bitlength(z) = 2*max(bitlength(x),bitlength(y))$

$O(n)$ time seems to trivially derive from the absence of any operation apart from bit interleaving, which is $O(1)$ for each pair of bits.

What bugs me is that in Regan (1992), the algorithm is more involved but claims identical time and space complexity. I guess I am misunderstanding something.

Is the Pigeon function really $O(n)$ in time? If the problem of integer pairing has such a simple solution, how come Cantor's and the Rosenberg-Strong pairing functions are cited so widely while having inferior performance characteristics?